# How to remove one of my installations?

Tags: re-installation

I installed ubuntu 8.10 one month ago then installed ubuntu 11.04 two weeks later. now I wanna remove one of them (ubuntu 8.10). how can I do that.

Answer (score 2):

To remove 8.10, just delete the partition that holds 8.10 using [gparted[image: usc_image]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gparted)and then from the current installation (11.04) run `sudo update-grub` in the terminal. As long as the Grub is not installed on the partition that holds 8.10, you should be golden :)